# How to decide the sequence of runnable

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, runnable

I'm doing an application in which I have to show a sequence of pictures: The sequence is the follow:

1. A red `X` has to be shown for 400 milliseconds
2. An image called "Screenshot" has to be shown for 500 milliseconds
3. An image called "Noise" has to be shown for 50 milliseconds
4. The "Noise" image disappear to make space for an `EditText`

But the results that comes out is the red `X` shown for 400 milliseconds and then a blank screen.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
private void startThread(){             
      handler.postDelayed(new TaskScreenshot(), 400);
      handler.postDelayed(new TaskNoise(), 500);
      handler.postDelayed(new TaskEditText(), 100);     
}

class TaskScreenshot implements Runnable{
   @Override public void run() {
      myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.googleplaybooks2);
      myImageView.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
      myImageView.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
   }
}

class TaskNoise implements Runnable{
   @Override public void run() {
      myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noise);
      myImageView.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
      myImageView.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
   }
}

class TaskEditText implements Runnable{
   @Override public void run() {
      myInputFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      myImageFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
}
```

The red `X` is already set in the `ImageView` before the sequence starts.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is `Runnable` the right way of doing this sequence?

Comment: may want to check executors http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Comment: Try to post the next delayed tasks at the end of the previous task. T1 run then post delayed T2. T2 run then post delayed T3 and so on...

Comment: Aubin what do you mean?

Comment: Looks like you're attempting to do a [frame animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `postDelayed` methods do not accumulate the delays. What you want to do is:

```
private void startThread(){             
      handler.postDelayed(new TaskScreenshot(), 400);
      handler.postDelayed(new TaskNoise(), 900);
      handler.postDelayed(new TaskEditText(), 1000);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() should be right choice if you want particular sequence for some runnable in your code.

Javadoc for newSingleThreadExecutor() is below

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates
>   due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
>   take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) **Tasks are
>   guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be
>   active at any given time.** Unlike the otherwise equivalent
>   newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be
>   reconfigurable to use additional threads.

you startThread method could be written as below

```
  private void startThread(){
  ExecutorService exec =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    exec.execute(new TaskScreenshot());
    exec.execute(new TaskNoise());
    exec.execute(new TaskEditText());
    exec.shutdown();
  }
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and `Runnable`?

Comment: Can I set a timer in the `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @DamianFox ScheduledExecutorService will is used for timer related functionality and it extends ExecutorService.